# Find the time in table Y closest to the time in table X

Tags: sql

I'm trying to match 2 tables that aren't a great match.

I have an `ATTENDANCE` table that records a persons name, email, and entrytime.

I have another table that lists an EVENT with a `STARTTIME` and `ENDTIME` (`datetime` fields).

People can mark the attendance early or also late, even hours later, so it can't be between those times, just the closest to that.

There are multiple `EVENTS` in the day, so my query needs to best guess - What event did they attend?

Comment: please show detailed schema information, sample data, expected result, and any SQL you may have created to try and solve this so far. Please also say which SQL product you are using exactly, and the version number, since the syntax and functions available can vary significantly. Without these pieces of information it's going to be much much harder to help you, if not impossible. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the schema of both tables? Also, assumption is there is a foreign key between the 2 tables that link the event to the attendance. If not, then it is a "best guess" of what event they attended and not the best thought out schema.

Comment: `from attendance a join event e on a.entrytime between e.starttime and e.endtime`?

Comment: @WEI_DBA You're right, it's not well thought out!  I've inherited the tables, and the data.  There's no direct relationshp, which is why I have to take a 'best guess' from the attendance time (entry time) and the event start & finish time....

Answer (score 0):

This query selects the closest starttime to each entrytime:

```
WITH TimeDifferences AS
(
    SELECT a.Entrytime, e.Starttime, Abs(DateDiff(MINUTE, a.Entrytime, e.Starttime)) AS Timediff
    FROM Attendance a
    CROSS JOIN Event e
)
SELECT t.Entrytime, t.Starttime
FROM Attendance a
INNER JOIN TimeDifferences t
ON a.Entrytime = t.Entrytime
AND t.Timediff =
(
    SELECT Min(Timediff)
    FROM TimeDifferences t2
    WHERE a.Entrytime = t2.Entrytime
)
```